# Is it possible to enable Lightning for Visualforce for a public force.com sites user?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I've got a visualforce page that's rendering a Lightning Component. I would like the component to work on a force.com site as the public guest user; however, the wrapper lightning app url with dependencies is throwing a 401

/[myapp].app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT

I'm assuming I need to make the app accessible to the guest user somehow. I'm missing the obvious location where this is done. I don't see it in the profile?

I apologize if it's in the docs, my search turned up no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guest user support for LC4VF is coming in a future release (working to get it into Spring'16 - safe harbor of course). This was not originally in scope for that release but we had to do most of the work for some internal projects that depend on it and I have only just now gotten the green light to access="global" a new interface that your LO app will just need to implement for guest user support to kick in.

Comment: hi @Doug, my current org is on Spring 16 and I am still not able to access lightning page in Force.com site after giving access global interface. Any other pointers on same or settings? It works in org but in site. It gives the same error as mentioned in initial question

Comment: Hi Doug, has guest user support been added in Summer 16?  I can't find anything in the release notes, but I'm wondering if I've missed it somewhere.

Comment: @DougChasman how is this feature coming along? Or is there any other way to do what the OP requested?